# Open ears text to speech (voice) not working when getting string from another class/controller (IOS, Objective c)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, openears

I am very new to objective c and OpenEars so please forgive me if I have some messy code and if I am lost in very simple problem.

Anyhow, I have two controllers in this application. The first being the default ViewController and the second one being a new one that I made called ReplyManagerController.

The code in the ViewController basically uses the one in the tutorial with some (maybe more some) changes.

EDIT:

The app is supposed to be a basic app where a user says something and the app replies.

But the original problem was that I could not get the string to display or TTS to work when my ViewController got it's string from another class/controller.

The answer in my below mentions that it was probably because my other class was calling my ViewController without the self.fliteController initialized.

How would I initialize the ViewController with self.fliteController initialized?

ViewController.m

```
- (void) pocketsphinxDidReceiveHypothesis:(NSString *)hypothesis recognitionScore:(NSString *)recognitionScore utteranceID:(NSString *)utteranceID {

NSString *strResult = hypothesis; //speech to text to string

ReplyManager* replyObject = [[ReplyManager alloc] init];
[replyObject speechResult:(NSString*)strResult viewController:self];
}

- (void) getReply:(NSString*)replyStr{

[self.fliteController say:replyStr withVoice:self.slt];

[self updateText:replyStr];
}

- (IBAction)updateText:(NSString*)replyStr{
labelOne.text = replyStr;
labelOne.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
labelOne.minimumFontSize = 0;

}
```

Any help will be great! Thanks!

ReplyManager.m

```
  - (void) speechResult:(NSString*)strResult {

    NSString *replystr;
    NSString *greetings = @"Hi!";
    NSString *sorry = @"Sorry I didn't catch that?";

    ViewController* getReply = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"HELLO"])
      { 
       replystr = greetings;
       [getReply getReply:(NSString*)replystr];
      }
    else
      {
       replystr = sorry;
       [getReply getReply:(NSString*)replystr];
      }
}
```

EDIT 2:

viewDidLoad Method

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   self.fliteController = [[OEFliteController alloc] init];
   self.slt = [[Slt alloc] init];

   self.openEarsEventsObserver = [[OEEventsObserver alloc] init];
   [self.openEarsEventsObserver setDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a timing issue where you're trying to use `fliteController` before it's been initialized.

In your `ViewController` class, where do you assign a value to the `fliteController` property? In an initializer? `-(void)viewDidLoad`?

In `ReplyManagerController` add:

```
ViewController* getReply = [[ViewController alloc] init];

// Add these lines
NSLog(getReply.fliteController); // Is this nil?
[getReply.view layoutIfNeeded];
NSLog(getReply.fliteController); // Is it still nil?
```

Does the above fix the problem? If so, you're probably initializing `fliteController` in `-(void)viewDidLoad`. What's the result of the two `NSLog` statements?

Comment: Yes I load the fliteController in - (void)viewDidLoad.

Comment: And I do get a null on the first NSLog and get something in the next

Comment: Well, there you go. The problem was that you alloc/init'd `ViewController`, but `-(void)viewDidLoad` never got called to initialize `fliteController`. Adding `[getReply.view layoutIfNeeded];` (or simply referencing `view`) caused `viewDidLoad` to run.

Comment: Alternatively, you could initialize `fliteController` in `ViewController`'s designated initializer. e.g., `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` Any initialization that's not dependent on the view controller's view should probably occur there anyway.

Comment: Oddly though the TTS still doesn't seem to work. Neither does the string show up on view. I feel like I messed somewhere big but I can't seem to find where

Comment: The `ViewController` instance created in `ReplyManager` is likely deallocating as soon as the method exits. After `ViewController* getReply = [[ViewController alloc] init];` add: `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController presentViewController:getReply animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: I think that did it!~ Thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116631/discussion-between-user2438817-and-lee-fastenau).

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewController* getReply = [[ViewController alloc] init];
```

Here you init a new `ViewController` which does not have `self.fliteController` defined most likely. You need to reuse previos controller, for example like this:

```
   [replyObject speechResult:(NSString*)strResult viewController:self];
```

So you can use already initialized `viewController` later. Overall it is better to initialize objects like `viewController` or `replyController` beforehand, not inside callback methods.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but I get an error saying: 'No visible @interface for ReplyManager declares the selector selectReply:viewController:'. Why is that?

Comment: It should be related to some other code you wrote. You probably need to ask another question and provide all necessary details.

Comment: Hi again, I fixed the previous error and have did it as you have shown, but it is still not working. There is still no voice speaking when I use the reply manager. Did I need to make ReplyManager a subclass or something like that?